# How to get parent from child

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So let's say I found that a value in database matches value entered by user through query. How can I find the parent of that value?

Ex. Let's say I enter in 35 as the age. 35 is also found in the database so how do I get the parent of that value (0)? Underlined in the picture.

I saw some similar questions asked but I can't seem to find a right answer to my question. Additionally, most of them are in different language.

[image]

Here is what I got so far:

```
 @IBAction func onDiagnose(_ sender: Any) {
        let ref1 = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://agetest.firebaseio.com/")
        let databaseRef = ref1.child("data")
        databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "age").queryEqual(toValue: Int(ageTextField.text!)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // if there is data in the snapshot reject the registration else allow it

            if (snapshot.value! is NSNull) {


               print("NULL")

            } else {


                //print(snapshot.value)
                //get parent
                //snapshot.ref.parent?.key! as Any
            }


        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Isn't snapshot.ref what you're looking for?

Comment: that outputs https://agetest.firebaseio.com/data which is not what I'm looking for. I want it to output "0". 0 is under data

Comment: OK, I think you want to iterate the children of the snapshot (since you may get more than one match) and look at their refs.

Comment: how would I do that? can you post a sample code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So you need to loop through the child nodes of the resulting snapshot to get at the individual results:

```
databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "age").queryEqual(toValue: Int(ageTextField.text!)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        print(child.key)     
    }
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Also see [listening to value events for lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: thank you, this is exact what I was looking for! What if I want to get another value such as "diagnosis" of that parent. How would I do that? Sorry, I am new to Firebase.